# At risk of getting blocked

Tags: support, reputation

Askubuntu tells me I'm at risk of getting blocked from asking any questions. I'd be grateful if the community would help me out with what i ask for, and if the question seems inappropriate, offer suggestions rather than closing it or marking it as inappropriate or unspecific and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [Meta-SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/how-can-i-understand-why-am-i-receiving-a-warning-that-i-could-be-blocked), I decided to take a look at your other profiles. Currently you have:

1. An [AU profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/185114/anas-ismail-khan) with:

   - One upvoted, open question
   - One on-hold question with zero score
   - One upvoted duplicate question
2. An [SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3700029/anas-ismail-khan) with:

   - One highly downvoted (-3), closed question
3. An [U&L profile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/72160/anas-ismail-khan) with:

   - One zero-score open question

Overall your contribution hasn't been very positive. Just on the basis of score, you have a net score of -1. Quoting Shog9:

> That's not awful, but it's definitely not great either. If the trend continues, you're gonna end up blocked. So, we warn you ahead of time so that you can do something about it: fix your previous questions and ask better questions in the future.

Comment: Look, i'm not a regular user, and im not exactly the best at stuff so i cant help others out much. I use it when i really need help with something and after a lot of searching i cant find an answer and trust me.. the experience hasn't been great for me either.. but these rules and strictness.. whats the point.. they only make it worse

Comment: and that duplicate stuff and all.. look, i know when what im asking is relevant and different.. i know what duplicate means too..